# How to redirect from iOS app notifications settings to app notification settings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist, root.plist

The best way to explain what I want to archieve is by using Facebook iOS app screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Facebook iOS app]

Clicking that button redirects user directly to Facebook app (notifications settings).

I am only able to add some switches and labels to root settings window (by using Settings.bundle.

So how can I redirects user from my app notifications settings to my app?

Thanks in advance for every help.

Comment: @ArshadShaik The only solution is accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use UNUserNotificationCenter and request authorization for `.providesAppNotificationSettings`

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound, .providesAppNotificationSettings])
```

Then use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method for handling:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {
    // Open settings view controller
}
```

---

### Swift

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound, .providesAppNotificationSettings])
        return true
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {
        // Open settings view controller
    }
}
```

### Objective-C

```
@interface TAXAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
    ////
@end

@implementation TAXAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionProvidesAppNotificationSettings) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            ///
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center openSettingsForNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
{
    // Open settings view controller 
}

@end
```

Comment: Note that if you already requested access before changing this, you'll need to re-request it. And if the Settings app was already open prior to adding that option, force quit it and relaunch to get the button to appear.

Comment: @JordanH still can't see that button